# CustomDataProvider for feature file (QAF)

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, dataprovider, qaf

I'm using QAF and it's amazing tool, but i have one problem.
Are there any ways to parameterize cucumber feature steps with custom data provider as it's done in BDD files?

For example, we can insert data from external file

```
Examples: {'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}
```

In .BDD it's done like this:

```
SCENARIO: Data provider with testng method argument and context
META-DATA: {"dataProvider":"dp-with-testngmethod-contex", "dataProviderClass":"com.qmetry.qaf.automation.impl.CustomDataProvider"}
# Comment '${value}'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found [in-built data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) does not satisfy your need then you can provide custom data provider. In case of [gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) you can provide it with `Examples`:

```
Examples: {"dataProvider":"dp-with-testngmethod-contex", "dataProviderClass":"com.qmetry.qaf.automation.impl.CustomDataProvider"}
```

Any of the [meta-data for data-provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#meta-data) can be used with `Examples`. 
Moreover with latest [BDD2 syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) you can also provide it as below:

```
@dataProvider:dp-with-testngmethod-contex
@dataProviderClass:com.qmetry.qaf.automation.impl.CustomDataProvider
@regression 
Scenario: my scenario
...
```

Comment: How exactly do we implement a custom data provider user861594?
There is no documentation on how to perform this, and i can't get it to work.

The reason i need a custom provider in the first place, is due to the default CSV data provider is performing automatic data type casting, and i don't want that... i need all the data to remain as Strings.

Comment: If you are looking for customdata provider class example, you can find on https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html it is testng dataprovider implementation returning Object[][] holding Map object. You don't need to create custom data provider if you are using csv, json or other supported files. Refer https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html