# Cucumber - How to configure QAF Gherkin Scenario Factory?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, qaf

I have a Cucumber project running thanks to JUnit with the following class:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "com.steps",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json"})
public class RunCucumber {
}
```

I want to use [QAF Gherkin Scenario Factory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) in order to put some scenario examples in external files in order to reuse them (ex : [Cucumber: Scenario Outline reusing examples table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716186/cucumber-scenario-outline-reusing-examples-table) or [CustomDataProvider for feature file (QAF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183430/customdataprovider-for-feature-file-qaf)).

I read the last section called "For Existing cucumber implementation" and did what it says, but I currently get an exception when running Cucumber with QAF (see edit section below).

**Java**: 1.8

**Cucumber** : 4.8.0

**Junit**: 4.12

---

src/test/resources/features/test.feature

```
Feature: Test for QAF

  Scenario: success
    Given my scenario works
```

src/test/java/com/steps/TestSteps.java

```java
@QAFTestStepProvider
public class TestSteps {

    @Given("my scenario works")
    public void myScenarioWorks() {
         assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Base on user861594 help, here is where I am:

- I downloaded the library [QAF 2.1.15](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmetry/qaf/2.1.15) through maven configuration.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

- I annotated my step class with @QAFTestStepProvider
- I created a xml configuration file for testNG in order to configure cucumber and run it with the QAF class called GherkinScenarioFactory:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestNG - Cucumber" verbose="0">
    <test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
        <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.steps" />
        <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="src/test/resources/features/test.feature" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

- I ran the previous configuration with the testNG plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (*test kind = suite*. I also can choose *Class, Method, Group, Pattern* or *All in package*)
- When running, I get the following exception (before the test, so it is ignored):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51974:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\IdeaProjects\perso\cucumber\target\test-classes;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\IdeaProjects\perso\cucumber\target\classes;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-java\4.8.0\cucumber-java-4.8.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-core\4.8.0\cucumber-core-4.8.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\gherkin\5.1.0\gherkin-5.1.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\tag-expressions\1.1.1\tag-expressions-1.1.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-expressions\7.0.2\cucumber-expressions-7.0.2.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable\1.1.14\datatable-1.1.14.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable-dependencies\1.1.14\datatable-dependencies-1.1.14.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-junit\4.8.0\cucumber-junit-4.8.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-spring\4.8.0\cucumber-spring-4.8.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\net\masterthought\cucumber-reporting\4.10.0\cucumber-reporting-4.10.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\velocity-tools\velocity-tools\1.4\velocity-tools-1.4.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.10.2\joda-time-2.10.2.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.9\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\3.2.0\plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.12.1\jsoup-1.12.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\owasp-java-html-sanitizer\owasp-java-html-sanitizer\20190610.1\owasp-java-html-sanitizer-20190610.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\27.1-jre\guava-27.1-jre.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\2.5.2\checker-qual-2.5.2.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.2.0\error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.17\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.17.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.2.0\json-path-2.2.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.2.1\json-smart-2.2.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.1\accessors-smart-1.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.3\httpclient-4.5.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.6\httpcore-4.4.6.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-xml\2.9.8\jackson-dataformat-xml-2.9.8.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.9.8\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.8.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.4\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\woodstox\woodstox-core\5.0.3\woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\qmetry\qaf\2.1.15\qaf-2.1.15.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-client\1.19\jersey-client-1.19.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-core\1.19\jersey-core-1.19.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\jsr311-api\1.1.1\jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\contribs\jersey-multipart\1.19\jersey-multipart-1.19.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\mimepull\mimepull\1.9.3\mimepull-1.9.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\contribs\jersey-apache-client\1.17.1\jersey-apache-client-1.17.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.8.9\aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.9\aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjtools\1.8.9\aspectjtools-1.8.9.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\jexcelapi\jxl\2.6.12\jxl-2.6.12.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.14\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.5\gson-2.8.5.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.10\testng-6.10.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.48\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0\guice-3.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\velocity\velocity-dep\1.4\velocity-dep-1.4.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.53.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.53.0\selenium-api-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.1.0\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.1.0\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\2.53.0\selenium-java-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.53.0\selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\2.53.0\selenium-edge-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.53.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.53.0\selenium-ie-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\2.53.0\selenium-safari-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.5.7.Final\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\2.53.0\selenium-support-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-leg-rc\2.53.0\selenium-leg-rc-2.53.0.jar;C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20180813\json-20180813.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander-1.27.jar" org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket51973 @w@C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp
10:00:20.385 [main] INFO  c.q.q.a.core.ConfigurationManager - ISFW build info: {qaf-Type=core, qaf-Revision=15, qaf-Version=2.1, qaf-Build-Time=20-Nov-2019 22:28:06}
10:00:20.409 [main] INFO  c.q.q.a.core.ConfigurationManager - Resource dir: C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\IdeaProjects\perso\cucumber\resources. Found property files to load: 0
10:00:20.417 [main] INFO  c.q.q.a.core.ConfigurationManager - Resource dir: C:\Utilisateurs\a754206\IdeaProjects\perso\cucumber\resources. Found property files to load: 0
include groups []
 exclude groups: [] Scanarios location: src/test/resources/features/test.feature 
10:00:20.430 [main] INFO  c.q.q.a.s.c.g.GherkinScenarioFactory - scenario.file.loc[Ljava.lang.String;@2a40cd94
10:00:20.511 [main] INFO  c.q.q.a.s.c.text.BehaviorScanner - loading feature file: src/test/resources/features/test.feature
10:00:20.542 [main] INFO  c.q.q.a.s.c.g.GherkinScenarioFactory - total test found: 1

Test ignored.
Preparing For Shut Down...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:178)
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFTestNGListener.report(QAFTestNGListener.java:234)
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFTestNGListener2.report(QAFTestNGListener2.java:174)
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFTestNGListener.onConfigurationFailure(QAFTestNGListener.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runConfigurationListeners(Invoker.java:1686)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleConfigurationFailure(Invoker.java:305)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:243)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

- I debbuged, and in fact there is a double error: a NullPointerException happens during the run (see below), so then we arrive in onConfigurationFailure, but then again there is a NullPointerException (the one above)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFTestNGListener.beforeInvocation(QAFTestNGListener.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeBeforeInvocationWithContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:92)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeBeforeInvocationWithContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:88)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(Invoker.java:557)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:494)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Recap of when and where the exceptions happen:

```java
// TestNG SuiteRunner#run begins
// Eventually we arrive in QAFTestBase where the first NullPointerException happens

public List<LoggingBean> getLog() {
        return (List<LoggingBean>) getContext().getObject(COMMAND_LOG); // NullPointerException. getContext() is OK but getContext().getObject(CHECKPOINTS) returns null
    }

// QAFTestNGListener#onConfigurationFailure is called
// Eventually we arrive in QAFTestBase again, where the second NullPointerException happens

public List<CheckpointResultBean> getCheckPointResults() {
        return (List<CheckpointResultBean>) getContext().getObject(CHECKPOINTS); // NullPointerException. getContext() is OK but getContext().getObject(CHECKPOINTS) returns null
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create XML configuration file to run your features:

```
<test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
   <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="pkg.to.look.for.steps" />
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

Refer documentation for [BDD configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html). Run it as TestNG test.

Which version of cucumber step implementation you have?
If it is cucumber 5+ add [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber) dependency. You can find latest dependency in [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmetry/qaf-cucumber). Also use [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmetry/qaf) (as of today QAF 2.1.15)

**EDIT:**

### Cucumber 4:

Cucumber 4 users can use [qaf-cucmber4](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber/tree/cucumber-4#qaf-cucumber4) and keep using cucumber **as it is** with additional capabilities. It will allow you to use external test data, and parameterize step arguments as well as meta-data rule and meta-data format. Below are steps:

1. add [qaf-cucumber4](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber/tree/cucumber-4#qaf-cucumber4) dependency. Make suer to put dependency before
   other cucumner dependencies.
2. add QAFCucumberPlugin (see junit example below).

You can then use [BDD2 syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) features which is super set of gherkin.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.QAFCucumberPlugin"}, <other options>)//
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

### Cucumber 5:

1. add [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber) dependency. Make suer to put dependency befor
   other cucumner dependencies.
2. To run using cucumner runner add QAFCucumberPlugin (see junit example above).
3. To Run using TestNG use QAF BDD2 factory with TestNG

Here is example TestNG configuration file.

```
<test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
   <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="pkg.to.look.for.steps" />
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory2" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

Note: qaf-cucumber4 is not supporting running with testng using bdd factory.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to run it as TestNG, thank you. I am using the last stable release of cucumber, so 4.8.0.

Comment: I now use the bundled IntelliJ IDEA TestNG plugin to run the XML configuration you mentioned (though I had to wrap its content inside the tag <suite>). Nevertheless I have a NullPointerException during the setupSuit phase, so the tests are not ran: 
**com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFTestNGListener.report(QAFTestNGListener.java:234)**
Do you think I miss something ? Or can it be because of the IntelliJ IDEA TestNG plugin ?

Comment: can you provide exception details? Is it blocking? Also it will be good if you can provide some details on how your step implementation looks. Alternate is you can upgrade to cucumber 5.0.0RC1 and run with Junit

Comment: It is blocking yes. I updated my original post with all the useful informations I could think of.

Comment: Refer updated comment. You can use cucumber runner with all existing cucumber implementation with [qaf-cucumber4](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber/tree/cucumber-4#qaf-cucumber4)

Comment: Yes I will probably use that if I can, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am currently trying to use qaf-cucumber but I am facing an issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59055379/qaf-cucumber-can-not-reference-data-from-csv-data-provider-in-bdd2-scenario-ou). Any more help is welcome !

Comment: @user861594,Can we use qaf with test cafe javascript framework?

Comment: qaf can be used with java/groovy not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the exceptions were due to the following dependency, which has nothing to do with QAF as it simply is a plugin to generate cucumber reports in html format:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency
```

Without it, everything is fine. I did not bother to dig why because I don't care and have no time for this.

---

I am now able to run tests with QAF, but it is important to note that:

- *@QAFTestStep* and *@QAFTestStepProvider* do not work with cucumber annotations of *io.cucumber.java.en.**, but only with their **deprecated** version of *cucumber.api.java.en.**. Otherwise there will be a *com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StepNotFoundException*
- Cucumber parameters like {string} must be escaped like \\{string\\} every single time. Otherwise there will be a *java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition*
- Spring dependency injection is more complex with TestNG than it is with Cucumber alone: steps classes must extends *AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests* (which imply to import the spring-test libray) and be annotated with *@ContextConfiguration*. Also I could not make this work, so may be it is even more complex when using QAF.

I discovered that while just scraching the surface of TestNG+QAF, so my opinion is that it is not worth the pain if like me you only want to use QAF for its feature of externalizing data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use qaf to run testng with cucumber, in your log there is "include groups []" shows that you didn't include your test case.
So you should add you test case in testng xml like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestNG - Cucumber" verbose="0">
    <test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
        <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.steps" />
        <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="src/test/resources/features/test.feature" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="@test"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And add @test tag in cucumber feature file:

```
Feature: Test for QAF
  @test
  Scenario: success
    Given my scenario works
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be posted in cucumberjs. From what I can see this is Java?

Comment: I do not get your question, can you reformulate ?

Comment: @Flyout91 you tagged cucumberjs . This doesn't look to be javascript related question

Comment: Corrected, thank you. I was too quick when I wanted to select cucumber-jvm.