# qaf-cucumber - can not reference data from CSV data provider in BDD2 scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, qaf

## Context

I want to use qaf-cucumber to take advantage of QAF features while **still using Cucumber with JUnit**. Mainly, I need QAF for its data provider feature, allowing to externalize scenario examples in .csv in order to use them across several scenarios and features.

**Junit**: 4.12

**Cucumber**: 5.0.0-RC2

**QAF**: 2.1.15

**qaf-cucumber**: 2.1.15-beta-3 (most recent version, as there is no release yet)

---

## Problem

When using the QAF tag `@dataFile` above a scenario to specify the location of the .csv:

- I get the INFO trace "c.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.CSVUtil - loading csv data file: src/test/resources/data/testdata.csv", as expected.
- the scenario is executed as many times as there are lines of examples in the .csv, as expected.
- **In the steps, references like `<column1>` or `${column1}` are considered as string instead of referencing the value of columns in the .csv**.

Also (but I don't seek any solutions for those):

1. The [QAF documentation about CSV](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/csv.html#character-separated-values) says that `@dataFile:resources/data/logintestdata.csv` is equivalent to `Examples: {"dataFile":"resources/data/logintestdata.csv"}` for BDD2, but the second one does not trigger any scenario, as if no examples where given.
2. The [QAF documentation about BDD2 syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) says that the Gherkin keyword `Scenario` should be used when using the QAF tag `@dataFile`. Nonetheless, doing so gives the stack trace below. Instead, the keyword `Scenario Outline` must be used.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.<init>(Collections.java:1026)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.<init>(Collections.java:1302)
    at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.java:1287)
    at gherkin.ast.ScenarioOutline.<init>(ScenarioOutline.java:13)
    at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.Bdd2Compiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.compilePickles(FeatureParser.java:59)
    at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.lambda$new$0(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:39)
    at java.util.function.BiFunction.lambda$andThen$0(BiFunction.java:70)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.lambda$null$2(ResourceScanner.java:128)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:67)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner$ResourceFileVisitor.visitFile(PathScanner.java:52)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForPath(PathScanner.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.PathScanner.findResourcesForUri(PathScanner.java:26)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.findResourcesForUri(ResourceScanner.java:111)
    at io.cucumber.core.resource.ResourceScanner.scanForResourcesUri(ResourceScanner.java:88)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.loadFeatures(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:62)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

---

## Example

Cucumber runner at `src/java/com`

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "com.steps",
        plugin = {"com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.QAFCucumberPlugin", "pretty"})
public class RunCucumber {
}
```

Feature at `src/test/resources/features`

```
Feature: Cucumber scenario with QAF data provider

  @dataFile:src/test/resources/data/testdata.csv
  Scenario Outline: Test
     Given my scenario works with the examples "<column1>" and "<column2>"
```

testdata.csv at `src/test/resources/data`

```
#col.seperator=|
column1|column2
example1_column1|example1_column2
example2_column1|example2_column2
```

Step at `src/test/java/com/steps`

```java
public class TestSteps {

    @Given("my scenario works with the examples {string} and {string}")
    public void myScenarioWorks(String value1, String value2) {
         // value1 equals "<column1>" and value2 equals "<column2>" !
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working with "Scenario Outline"?

Comment: This looks like bug report rather than question.

Comment: With "Scenario Outline" and example section it works fine. With "Scenario Outline" and no example section but @dataFile, the scenario is played as many times as there are examples, but the references are treated as string. With "Scenario" (and @dataFile) the scenario is not played even once, as if there were no example. If it is a bug then it is a pretty big one. I might report that then, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with 2.1.15 and it worked for me. I was  also getting above behavior with qaf-cucumber 2.1.15-beta-3 but when updated to qaf-cucumber 2.1.15 it worked fine.

Comment: Can you please provide an example ? It still does not work for me with 2.1.15