# QAF-Cucumber with TestNG is throwing class not found exception

Tags: qaf

I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception while running qaf-cucumber with Testng.  Tried run as both with Maven and TestNG with same error. Not sure what i am doing wrong here. Here is my source and folder structure

TestNG XML:

```
<suite name="TestNG - Cucumber" verbose="0">
    <test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
        <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="src/test/java" />
        <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="Scenarios" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Feature file:

```
Feature: Test for QAF

  Scenario: success
    Given my scenario works
```

POM File:

```
<dependencies>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.15</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>qaf-cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.15</version>
 </dependency>


   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>  
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>




  </dependencies>
```

Step Definition class:

```
package StepDefinitions;

import com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.QAFTestStepProvider;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;


@QAFTestStepProvider
public class TestSteps {

    @Given("my scenario works")
    public void myScenarioWorks() {
         System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.160 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-04T19:03:59+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project BRDWCucumberQAF: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer2
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[ERROR]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
[ERROR]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[ERROR]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
[ERROR]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
[ERROR]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
[ERROR]     at org.testng.TestNG.addServiceLoaderListeners(TestNG.java:961)
[ERROR]     at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:898)
[ERROR]     at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:988)
[ERROR]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer2
[ERROR]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[ERROR]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[ERROR]     ... 33 more
```

Similar question here

[Cucumber - How to configure QAF Gherkin Scenario Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980569/cucumber-how-to-configure-qaf-gherkin-scenario-factory/60520551?noredirect=1#comment107067502_60520551)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, TestNG 7 had removed `IAnnotationTransformer2` which is used by the framework.Remove testng dependecy from pom or set it to `6.10` and it should work.

Furthermore, QAF-cucumber supports cucumber 5. if you want to use cucumber 4 you may try qaf-cucumber4. Alternative for your case, you can set below property to use steps from cucumber 4 without using qaf-cucumber:

```
step.annotation.pkgs=io.cucumber.java
```